# Where should controller-like code be written in my vb.net app?

Tags: vb.net

I am refactoring an existing project that is one large file. All form controls live in a single form, and all event handlers live in the form's code behind.

I am refactoring out a piece of the UI into a User Control. One piece of this UI is an 'Add Contract' button. This goes to my data layer, adds a row to a DataTable, and various grids in other parts of form are updated with the new row.

My question is, where should I put the event handler for the button click in the User Control?

1. I could leave the event handler code in the parent form, and use `AddHandler` in the User Control to reference the parent form's sub
2. I could write all the event handler code in the User Control. In this case, I'd need to access the parent form to get a reference to the data layer.

I come from a web background where I'm used to the 'controller' handling this sort of thing.  I suppose my parent form is turning into a kind of controller - but is this a good practice? Should I have a separate class that coordinates user interactions with my model layer, or, once I separate out all the UI into separate user controls, will the main form be a good place for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user control should raise events that the form hosting the user control will handle. If the user control has a reference to the form, then the user control is not reusable in any other context; in other words, the user control is tightly coupled to that one form and form X would break if it tried to use the user control.

Note: If your form is the only thing that will use the user control, then there is not much re-usability value in making it a user control at all. Kind of similar to it is not much use to make an interface if there is only one implementation of said interface. That said from an organization standpoint, user controls can be used to clean up a crowded form. It also has the benefit of allowing for the dynamic loading of content in user controls.

There is nothing wrong with your parent form becoming the controller.

---

Here is a quick example (in this case the clicking of the button in the user control) of how you can raise events from your user control and subscribe to the event in the form:

```
Public Class UserControlClass
    ' Define event that will be raised by user control to anyone interested in handling the event
    Public Event UC_Button1Click()

    ' Mechanism to allow event to be raised by user control
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent UC_Button1Click()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now in your form class, you need to add a handler for the event raised by the user control, like this:

```
AddHandler userControl1.UC_Button1Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
```

Finally, you would create the method that is referenced in the `AddressOf` syntax, like this:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
    ' Do something here
End Sub
```

Comment: This makes sense. My idea of moving the related UI controls to a User Control was to just isolate some of the UI logic & naming of controls. Right now there are dozens and dozens of controls all in the main form. How else could I go about tidying this up, if not through user controls?

Comment: @SamSelikoff - sorry, I was a bit harsh, I meant there is no re-usability use of a tightly coupled user control to a form. See updated answer. Thanks for making me realize that I needed to clarify that. :-)

Comment: Makes total sense. Now to find how to raise events from my user controls! I'm glad this is the pattern, though. It's what I'm familiar with from Ember.js.

Comment: @SamSelikoff - I updated the answer with some code to get you going with events in the user control and handling the raised event in the form class, hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I've got one more quick question, if you have a minute: can you share BindingSources from the main form to user controls using the designer?

Comment: @SamSelikoff - never tried do anything with binding sources and user controls, sorry. :-(